# .NET CMS with custom authentication

Tags: asp.net, .net, authentication, content-management-system, asp.net-authentication

I know there's tons of questions about .NET based CMS out there, but I have some specifics things I'm looking for.

1) Be able to leverage our application's existing authentication (We have our own implementation of of `System.Web.Security.MembershipProvider` as well as `MembershipUser`)

2) Be able to restrict who can view certain pages/segments based on our custom roles, in addition to restrictions on who can edit them.

Maybe most of them support this, but I haven't had much luck finding which ones specifically satisfy these requirements.

(Being lightweight is also a plus, I've read about Orchard and N2)

Comment: @ the close vote, Too localized?  We can't be the only ones that want to integrate a CMS into an existing application with custom authentication.  I was thinking the vote was for a duplicate question I missed.

Comment: Maybe it is pretty localized 2 days left on bounty and no answers that have direct experience doing this.  I thought this would be a somewhat common requirement.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how much this will help you but here goes. We did a search last year for .NET content management systems and I wasn't super thrilled. There are a ton of commercial systems that are really expensive and appear to be crap.

I checked out N2 first. It seemed really clean, but it was way too barebones for our purposes. We would have had to do a ton of custom development to meet our needs. It's really a CMS framework instead of a CMS product.

Umbraco was the other system we took a serious look at. It has a lot more features built in and it's a fairly nice system as long as you don't mind a little XSLT. It does use the standard membership provider framework, so that's in your favor. I don't really know whether the roles will do what you want though. But since it's free you can play with it to see if it meets your needs.

As for Orchard, I don't know much about it. It wasn't around when we were looking, but it seems interesting. I couldn't tell in a reasonable amount of time how it handles membership and roles on the back end. It does seem like it's geared towards smaller sites, so it might be a little limiting in that respect.

Answer (score 1):

We've been using Telerik's [Sitefinity](http://www.sitefinity.com/) product with custom forms authentication. You can use forms authentication out of the box or you can customise it. It does make use of the provider model too.

More information [on custom authentication can be found here](http://www.sitefinity.com/devnet/forums/sitefinity-4-x/general-discussions/custom-authentication-role-and-profile-providers-example.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest looking into AxCMS (at AxCMS.net).  It is complete, pluggable and has extensive documentation.  Specific documentation about their implementation of Membership and Security is available at : http://help.axcms.net/en_help_concepts_security.AxCMS
Microsoft's Scott Gu recommends it here at http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/02/02/437220.aspx

Answer (score 0):

[EPiServer](http://www.episerver.com) is a commercial ASP.NET based CMS. It is essentially a set of .NET assemblies that you reference and build into your ASP.NET application to turn it into a first class CMS.

It makes use of standard ASP.NET features like the provider model so you can swap bits out.

Comment: I'm having trouble making it past the marketing-speak to get to the meat of how it works and what the API looks like etc.  Also I can't seem to find pricing info on their site.